# Why do webpages sometimes load without any styling whatsoever?

Tags: css, browser

I'm sure we've all seen this behavior at some point of time or the other.

When you load a webpage, the developers have usually spent a lot of time making it look nice on various devices and browsers. However, sometimes the browser just chooses to ignore all styling, and display a webpage that looks nothing like intended. Here's an example of the SO Chat itself:

[image]

[image]

Can anybody tell me how and why this happens? I've seen it across Firefox, Safari and Chrome myself (don't know if it happens in IE, but it probably does)

Comment: Possibly an error loading style sheets? Server timeout? Run Chromes Element Inspector and look for missing resources. A single file failing to load can screw up quite a bit ^.^

Comment: Because the css failed to load somehow. Especially true if the site uses multiple css files and only some of them don't come across

Comment: the HTML first loads and then applies the CSS Styles. usually it takes fraction of secs. But At times if the Browser didnt receive any CSS files from the server you will get the css switching off version off the site

Comment: What's wrong with this question? I would like to know why this question "will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". Surely, there may be various correct answers for this question as a CSS may not load properly for various reasons, but does that warrant the closure of the question?

Comment: It is actually mostly a chrome  bug in this particular case, people. As chrome also has the bugs to forget any javascript induced stylings or mess up responsive designs. It's because of a "compile pages faster" way which makes chrome sometimes skip something a bit too important.

Also, I too, wonder why this question has been closed. I think it's a great question which needs answers.

Comment: Try asking it in Meta Stack Overflow...

Comment: I've seen this on Safari iPad, Firefox desktop, and Chrome desktop - I would love to know what causes it.

Comment: I second to reopen this question. Its a common rendering issue and there should be nothing wrong in discussing what causes this issue.

Comment: I'm glad I stumbled upon this discussion. Is it me or does it sometimes seem like some of these questions get closed prematurely?

Comment: How to reopen this question? It's a common problem that needs solutions.

Comment: I too would like to know the possible answers for this.

Comment: I have just started seeing this recently - across multiple websites - so it appears to be not related to just one website. Perhaps my internet connection is bad? Speed test shows roughly 50/20 mbps. I've rebooted routers, modems, switches

Comment: I've faced this problem too. More than once my webpages appeared without styles when opened for the first time, and I had to refresh the page. I'm afraid someone visiting my websites for the first time might see something like this.